# How do I get client's local time from the back end?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, timestamp, localtime

What I do is to get the client's local time using JavaScript, then send the result to php using Ajax. I manipulate it in php to display values of certain timestamps in the client's local time. However, I keep getting the server time being displayed.

Here are my codes:

**JavaScript**

```
var now = new Date().toLocaleString();

xmlhttpupdates.open("POST", "updates.php", true);
xmlhttpupdates.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttpupdates.send("localnow="+now);
```

**PHP**

```
$localnow = $_POST["localnow"];

foreach ($allmsgsz as $allmsgs){

    $timestamp = strtotime($allmsgs[4]);
    $eventtimediff = strtotime($localnow) - $timestamp;
    $currentlocaltime = strtotime($localnow) - $eventtimediff;
    $time = date("Y-m-d (h:i a)",$currentlocaltime);
    echo $time;

}
```

Comment: It seems you need to look at the "make some calculations" PHP code.  It may not be usnig the input it gets from the client, and determining the date on its own.  That's certainly what the behavior you describe suggests.  Note that times are stored internally as universal numeric values, and time zones are applied for formatting.  If you are sending the date in that format, the server won't know what the time zone is, unless you send that too.  You could also just send the internal value to and from the server, and apply the time zone after it comes back.

Comment: Thanks about this. This clue really helped in getting it work.

Answer (score 2):

As PHP runs in server-side only, you can't get that information: you will need javascript

Solution:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
var x = new Date()
document.write(x)
</script>';
```

Instad of "echo" you can just use a variable

Comment: The thing is, after I've gotten the date in JavaScript, I'll have to send it to php so as to make some calculations with other php variables. The problem comes after the JavaScript date variable is sent to php. I'll end up with a server time.

Comment: The easiest way would be to send the date in UTC.  `toLocaleString` strips time zone information so the server doesn't know in which timezone the date is. You should use `toUTCString` instead.

Comment: Thanks about this. This solved my problem.